# Sharing memory from the linux kernel to user space in single user mode

Tags: linux, kernel, driver

I have a kernel module that allocates memory and I would like to share this memory with a user process.  In normal mode we can only do that with: mmap, /proc, shmem, etc.  but in single user mode, for embedded devices, isn't there a way to share a simple pointer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Single user mode" is a convention defined by userspace. It has no significance to the kernel; all of the same rules apply as "normal mode".

If you want to access memory -- *any* memory -- from userspace, you will need to map that memory into the process somehow. Using `mmap()` on a special file or device node is the most natural way of doing this.

Comment: I think the single user mode should disable these access rules because nobody cares about multiuser modes in embedded devices.

Comment: @PhilBouchard Unfortunately, you are alone in thinking that. Memory protection is just as important in embedded devices as it is elsewhere.

Comment: If you have thoroughly tested your processes and you "trust" them then I think there should be a way to talk directly to the kernel and do whatever you want (for embedded devices only of course).

Answer (score 1):

The pseudo sysfs file system (`/sys`) was intended for this very purpose (expose kernel data to userspace). You may also write to these data structures from user space.

Check out [Greg Kroah-Hartman's Driver Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CqDUfiH2PzQ)

Read [SysFS Documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sysfs.txt)

Comment: Thanks for the info, I can see sysfs is like ramfs, which is exactly what I am looking for!

Comment: @PhilBouchard Are you sure? sysfs has nothing in common with ramfs, beyond that they are both filesystems.

Comment: I meant that the sysfs can be read like a ramfs (direct access to memory)

Comment: @PhilBouchard Neither sysfs nor ramfs provides "direct access to memory".

Comment: Well the ramfs is a file system inside the RAM memory, right?  So that's a direct access for that file system.

Comment: @PhilBouchard Not really. Access to files in ramfs has to go through system calls (`read`, `write`, `mmap`, etc), just as if they were in a normal filesystem. The only difference for ramfs is that the files are never written out to persistent storage.

Comment: DMA in Linux is only implemented through virtual memory, you will never truly have direct access to memory in userspace. https://static.lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch15.pdf But thanks to the abstraction, you can *think* that you do :) if you are programming a real time application you might want to consider mmap a region and locking it so it doesnt get paged out. Locking pages has it's ramifications though

Comment: Ok so the best way is using mmap().  I just changed the checkmark to help others looking for the same solution.